# Entity framework - Return GUID from database first stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a method which calls a stored procedure that is existing in the database

```
public Guid GetUserID(string userName)
{
  using (var entities = new entities ())
  {
    return  Guid.Parse(entities.Database.SqlQuery<Guid>(
                       "dbo.[GetUserID] @UserName",
                       new Object[] { new SqlParameter("@UserName",
                                                        userName)
                                                  }).ToString());
  }
}
```

And my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserID] 
 @UserName NVARCHAR(100)
 AS
 BEGIN 
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM [DBO].[USER] WHERE USERNAME = @UserName
        ORDER BY CREATEDON DESC
END
GO
```

I added some logs and getting the following error:

```
Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid.Parse(String input)
```

Whats causing the above error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx) `SqlQuery` returns a collection of results. If you're only expecting one result back you need to call `Single` or `First`:

```
var userIdQuery = entities.Database.SqlQuery<Guid>(
                   "dbo.[GetUserID] @UserName",
                   new Object[] { new SqlParameter("@UserName", userName)});

// userIdQuery is a collection of Guids.
// We need to take either the first one, or ensure there
// is only one:    
Guid.Parse(userIdQuery.Single().ToString());
```

Be aware that `Single()` will throw an exception if no result is returned as well as if more than one result is returned.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That resolved my issue. Breaking my head from yesterday to figure out what the actual issue was.

Answer (score 0):

A GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) is a specific data type in SQL Server, Entity Framework, and other sources. It is represented as a 32 digit hexadecimal number  with 4 dashes, like this: `B98332DB-F5E0-4022-860F-9A42A7DEB965`

You are attempting to assign a username, which is almost certainly nor a 32 digit hexadecimal number with four dashes, to a GUID data format when you use `public Guid`.

Change the data type of the proc from Guid to String or some other more correct data type.

---

Edit: I read the original entry incorrectly, and the above is incorrect. However, the error message indicates that the value being passed to Guid.Parse is not a string representation of a GUID.

So, what value is actually being stored in the `Id` field?  Is it an identity field, an actual GUID (in which case you don't need to .Parse it), a string, or ??

Comment: The `username` is being passed into a parameter on the SqlQuery - however the OP is then passing the SqlQuery, not the single element in it to `TryParse`.

Comment: You are right, and I misread this. But, based on the error message, is the `Id` field being returned a GUID or an Identity field?